# Matching two lists in python

Tags: python

I have two lists with different lengths.

```
list1=['T','P','M','M','A','R','k','M','G','C']
list2=['T','P','M','M','A','R','k','S','G','C','N']
```

By comparing `list1` and `list2`: The results must be:

```
new_list1=['T','P','M','M','A','R','k','mis','M',  'G','C','mis']    
new_list2=['T','P','M','M','A','R','k','S',  'mis','G','C','N']
```

The method is by matching the elements in two lists with duplicates. If there are a non-matching elements in the same position. For example in `list1` there are three copies of `M`, in the `list2` there are two copies. The results must refer to missing `M` from `list2` in this position. The character `S` is missing from `list1`, results also must assign to missing.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: please show us the code you have written that attempts to do this, and explain how it is not working for you

Comment: Please at least provide an exact description of the types of mismatches you need to handle and go from there. The general case of this problem is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_string). If you can reduce it to *edit distance*, start with [Hirschberg's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirschberg's_algorithm).

Comment: You have to define which list is the main. Guess what you need to get from input list1 = ['a', 'b'] list2 = ['b', 'a']

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "mis" is a special value:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def create_matchs(alst, blst, mis="mis"):
    for a, b in zip_longest(alst, blst, fillvalue=mis):
        if a == b or mis in (a, b):
            yield a, b
        else:
            yield mis, b
            yield a, mis

list1 = ['T','P','M','M','A','R','k','M','G','C']
list2 = ['T','P','M','M','A','R','k','S','G','C','N']
new_list1, new_list2 = zip(*create_matchs(list1, list2))
print(new_list1)
print(new_list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try it. Its simple:

```
list1=['T','P','M','M','A','R','k','M','G','C']
list2 =['T','P','M','M','A','R','k','S','G','C','N']

if len(list1) > len(list2):
        diff = len(list1) - len(list2)
        for i in range(0, diff):
                list2.append('mis')
else:
        diff = len(list2) - len(list1)
        for i in range(0, diff):
                list1.append('mis')

new_list1 = []
new_list2 = []
for i in zip(list1,list2):
        if i[0] == i[1]:
                new_list1.append(i[0])
                new_list2.append(i[1])
        elif i[0] == 'mis' or i[1] == 'mis':
                new_list1.append(i[0])
                new_list2.append(i[1])
        else:
                new_list1.append(i[0])
                new_list2.append('mis')

                new_list1.append('mis')
                new_list2.append(i[1])

print new_list1
print new_list2
```

Output:

```
['T', 'P', 'M', 'M', 'A', 'R', 'k', 'M', 'mis', 'G', 'C', 'mis']
['T', 'P', 'M', 'M', 'A', 'R', 'k', 'mis', 'S', 'G', 'C', 'N']
```